# Is there any way in Pinescript to round to a specific number?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Is there any way to round to a specific number, say to the closest increment of 5?
For example,
414.2 to 415
138.5 to 140
112.1 to 110

I know Pinescription has basic ceiling and floor functions, but nothing specifying particular units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in function for this but this is a simple math question. You can write your own function for it.

Simply divide the number by 5 and round it. This way you would eliminate the decimal points. And then multiply by 5 again.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

f_round(num, div) => (div * (math.round(num / div)))

div = 5
num1 = 414.2
num2 = 138.5
num3 = 112.1
num4 = 100
num5 = 112.5

if (barstate.islast)
    s1 = "Num: " + str.tostring(num1) + " -> " + str.tostring(f_round(num1, div))
    s2 = "Num: " + str.tostring(num2) + " -> " + str.tostring(f_round(num2, div))
    s3 = "Num: " + str.tostring(num3) + " -> " + str.tostring(f_round(num3, div))
    s4 = "Num: " + str.tostring(num4) + " -> " + str.tostring(f_round(num4, div))
    s5 = "Num: " + str.tostring(num5) + " -> " + str.tostring(f_round(num5, div))
    s = s1 + "\n" + s2 + "\n" + s3 + "\n" + s4 + "\n" + s5

    label.new(bar_index, high, s, textcolor=color.white)
```

[image]